# how to pass pem files and other secrets to AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have a project that is using packer and needs pem files to do some ssh tasks.  I'm trying to get this automated with CodeBuild.

What is the best way (or any way) to get a pem file (or any other secret) to AWS CodeBuild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SSM Parameter Store secure string to store your private keys.

Parameter Store uses AWS KMS to encrypt and decrypt the parameter values of secure string parameters. That means you can create a customer managed CMK and control who can use this key to decrypt the parameters by using key/IAM policies.

Use put-parameter to store the key as a secure string.

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name mypem01 --type SecureString --key-id 1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab --value "<PEM_file_content>"
```

In buildspec, use the following command to fetch the key.

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name mypem01 --with-decryption --output text --query Parameter.Value
```

You should attach the following IAM policy to CodeBuild service role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-1:123456789012:parameter/EC2PEM/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:123456789012:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab"
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM users need the following policy to create a secure string parameter:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:PutParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:111122223333:parameter/FinancialParameters/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab"
        }
    ]
}
```

See [How Parameter Store Uses AWS KMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-parameter-store.html#parameter-store-encrypt) for further details.